# How to assign a value to a column, where the subset has 0 rows without error

Tags: r, subset, assign

Lets say we have a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=c("a","b","c"))
```

I can assign a new value to column b like this:

```
df[df$a==2]$b <- "z"
```

But if the subset has 0 rows, an error occurs, which will cause problems when the loop is running inside another loop, for example.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  df[df$a==i,]$b <- "d"
    }
```

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Use the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to avoid any error from the `factor` class

Comment: I dont understand. Where to use it?

Comment: In the `data.frame` call i..e `df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=c("a","b","c"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: That doesnt really help - the problem is that there is no 4 in df$a, so it will display an error when the loop encounters that.

Comment: I am not getting any error with  `df$b[df$a==4] <- "z"`  You are first subsetting the rows, then extracting 'b'.  Instead of that get the logical vector and extract the 'b'

Comment: so why not `for (i in 1:nrow(df))` ?

Comment: Because in the data i am using i dont know if there, in a specific year, is no rows with a specific value. Ofcourse i could change 1:4 to something else...

Comment: $akrun That was my fix also, but i dont understand the difference between     `df$b[df$a==4] <- "z"` and `df[df$a==4]$b <- "z"`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check if there are no rows, and only update the data frame when there are some with:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
    if (nrow(df[df$a==i,])) df[df$a==i,]$b <- "d"
}
```

Comment: True, and that would solve the problem. But as akrun pointed out in the comments, just moving the $b in before the subsetting would solve the problem, in a more elegant way i think.